# QGIS: How to render multiline labels correctly?

Tags: qgis

I am very new to QGIS. I want to label multiple points with their specific name as well as their altitude.

For this, I wrote a HTML label expression:

```html
format(
    '<b>Anchor %1</b><br>%2 m',
     "field_1",
    round($z, 1)
)
```

I want the altitude to be located below the name, so I added a `<br>` element.
In the preview, everything looks good:

[image: Preview for multiline label]

But on the map, only the first line is displayed:

[image: Multiline label on the map]

Is this some weird mismatch for supported HTML tags between the preview and the actual map, so it chokes on the `<br>`? Or is everything but the first line clipped and I have to enable some checkbox for multiline labels?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using HTML? Why not just regular QGIS expressions like `'Anchor ' || "field_1" || '\n' || round($z,1) || ' m'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can simplyfy your function a little bit with this 2 ways of getting the goal ([based on this solution, where you can also find that font size can be changed](https://north-road.com/2022/09/09/mixed-format-labels-in-qgis-coming-soon/)).

This is one way: `'<b>' || "NOME10" || '</b><p>' || "PODE10" || ' m'`
You just need to chain your text using this double bars, like here:
[image]
[image]

You can also simplify, (if you dont need those HTML customization of fonts and bold, etc). Like here:

[image]

With this you don't even need to add the "". Very simple.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot I can just use `<p>` for forcing a newline. Works, thank you!